# Why do so many login webpages seperate email and password fields?

Tags: login

I've been noticing that many popular login pages separate email and password fields on separate "sections" or pages.

Is there a UX benefit or reason for this that I'm not aware of?
[image: Yahoo! Mail login]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps the user to understand if the email address they have entered is correct before they proceed to entering a password.

If you are unsure about what credentials you used to create an account, guessing both the email address and password means you are more likely to be entering one incorrectly, but you don't know which.

However, if you enter just the email and it is wrong, then you know it is the email address which is wrong as oppose to wondering if the password is incorrect too.

Answer (score 2):

"Less is more", Provide user the only information which is easy to digest on one go, It also keeps users to engage into website/app, while it also makes users keep the focus on only few information.

Chunking is a very effective thing to present something in a manageable way.